# TYPO3/Powermail: Howto to store plugin pid in hidden form field

Tags: typo3, powermail

I want to store the page id of a Powermail plugin in the form data. I would like to setup a hidden field and prefill it with the page id of the plugin.

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill.pid = TEXT
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill.pid.field = pid
```

The above code does not help: I only get the pid of the Powermail template, not that of the plugin.

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Or a bit shorter:

```html
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill.pid = TEXT
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill.pid.data = TSFE:id
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill.pid = TEXT
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill.pid.stdWrap.data = TSFE:id
```